# « Ne pas finir », « ne pas en finir » ou « ne plus en finir » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, locutions, en

Quelle est la différence entre ces expressions? J'ai entendu la chanson *La nuit n'en finit plus* de Petula Clark, mais qu'est-ce que ce « en » remplace ici ? Quand on dit, « J'en suis sûr » par exemple, ça veut dire « Je suis sûr de ça ». Mais je ne comprends pas la signification du « en » dans le titre de la chanson.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour toutes vos réponses! J'ai toujours un problème avec ce prénom adverbial "en".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"En" ne remplace rien car "en finir" est une expression toute faite. "La nuit n'en finit plus" veut dire que la nuit s'éternise, qu'il semble que le jour ne viendra jamais.

"Ne pas en finir" "Ne plus en finir" sont semblables et veulent dire "s'éterniser".
"En finir avec quelque chose" veut dire qu'il faut que cela cesse. Ex: "Il faut en finir avec l'austérité"."Je veux en finir avec ces problèmes". Cela exprime aussi une lassitude de la situation.

Answer (score 3):

"N'en pas finir" and 'n'en plus finir" are fixed constructions used to describe something as "being too long."  So in the title and wherever in the song the phrase occurs with the "en" in it (La nuit n'en finit plus), Ms Clark is saying "The night is too long" (or "The night is [seems] never-ending" in a figurative, exaggerated sense).

She omits the "en" (La nuit ne finit plus) in the last verse (and in two earlier verses using the future tense [La nuit ne finira donc pas/jamais], however, and this omission permits one to interpret "finir" more literally and therefore much more desperately as "The night is not (ever) [going to] end.

Answer (score 1):

Finir attend un complément d'objet direct en principe : on finit quelque chose (ex : "finir sa soupe", "finir son travail").

"Je ne veux pas en finir" porterait sur moi (= je ne veux pas finir moi / je ne veux pas mourir)

"La nuit n'en finit pas" porte sur la nuit, qui ne se termine pas.