# Sens de « en » dans « ça n'en finit plus/jamais »

Tags: grammaire, sens, en

Il me semble que cette phrase est parfaitement compréhensible sans « en » déjà... Ça sert à quoi de l'ajouter ?

[image]

Comment: [« Ne pas finir », « ne pas en finir » ou « ne plus en finir » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12948/358)

Comment: @None Merci, c'est très clair !

Comment: Les sens sont légèrement différents. *Ça n'en finit plus* : C'est interminable, *Ça ne finit plus* : Ça devait finir, ce n'est plus le cas.